# Not sure if this capacitor will blow up

Tags: voltage, capacitor, amperage, charge, watts

so i have just bought a fan controller(silverstone cpf04)[image] and it is rated with 2200μF and i am planning to connect 7 fans to it.

(NF-F12)[image]4 fans are each rated with 12v operating voltage 3.6w input power and is rated 0.4amp @ 12v.

(NF-A14)[image]3 fans are each rated with 12v also but with 6.6w input power and is rated 0.84amp @ 12v.

I have tried doing some maths myself using a capacitance, charge and voltage calculator but I still am not sure if cant find out whether if it will blow up the fan controller.[image] I know this is a q&a for electrical engineering but I don't know where else to go. Pictures are attached to save your time. Tia.

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking, and how a capacitor comes into it. I'd say the mention of capacitor size is 'marketing material', but not sure why. You need to check the fan controller is happy driving the load you intend to connect.

Comment: ohhh, im just afraid that itll blow up as i have fan controllers blow up before and from what ive told its because the voltage is too high. so it's all cool?

Comment: The output current and voltage ratings of the controller must be adequate. It appears the controller may have connectors for 8 outputs. The capacitor voltage rating must be adequate for the controller supply voltage. There is not enough information here to begin to evaluate anything.

Comment: Since the capacitor is internal, it is out of your control. That makes this a question about whether or not the product is adequate for your purpose. Carefully read the product page including question and comments from other uses and seller responses. http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?area=en&pid=526

Answer (score 3):

That thing (in my opinion) does not qualify for the name of a fan controller. It's just a box which relays the PWM signal it gets from the mainboard to all eight connected fans. It does some trickery to get back a valid speed signal.

The power is delivered by a SATA power connector.

The capacitor is inside the box hooked up to the 12V of the SATA connector to provide a locally stabilized voltage to the fans - might be a good idea if 8 fans are doing PWM at the same time.

[image: inside picture]

Taken from the [product page](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?area=en&pid=526).

It has a 16 V electrolytic cap, so the voltage rating is fine. It is electrolytic, so it will fail at some time in the future - maybe the reason why they put it there in the first place (that's a bit harsh).

Comment: The "trickery to get a valid speed signal" seems to be that the speed ouptut is only connected to the lower right connector's speed signal... like the one in red in the picture on the black background on [this page](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811999309) which says "speed detection*"... pretty high tech LOL

Comment: @peufeu .... I read that note on "speed detection only supported on the glossy side", which sounded like more than one port... Yeah pretty nifty to connect a single port.

Comment: It has redundancy! Even if the other 7 fans get stuck it'll keep "working"...

Comment: @peufeu are you working in marketing?